# Difference between predict and fittedvalue in statsmodel

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have a very basic question, which I can somehow not find a real answer for.

Assuming I have a model:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
model = smf.ols(....).fit()
```

What is the difference between `model.fittedvalues` and `model.predict` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`model.predict` is a method for predicting values, so you can provide it an unseen dataset:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,2),columns=['X','Y'])

model = smf.ols('Y ~ X',data=df).fit()

model.predict(exog=pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3]}))
```

If you do not provide the exog argument, it returns the prediction by calling the data stored under the object, you see this under the [source code](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.html):

```
def predict(self, params, exog=None):
        """
        Return linear predicted values from a design matrix.

        Parameters
        ----------
        params : array_like
            Parameters of a linear model.
        exog : array_like, optional
            Design / exogenous data. Model exog is used if None.

        Returns
        -------
        array_like
            An array of fitted values.

        Notes
        -----
        If the model has not yet been fit, params is not optional.
        """
        # JP: this does not look correct for GLMAR
        # SS: it needs its own predict method

        if exog is None:
            exog = self.exog

        return np.dot(exog, params)
```

On the other hand, `model.fittedvalues` is a property and it is the fitted values that are stored. It will be exactly the same as model.predict() for reasons explain above.

You can look at the [methods](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.predict.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.predict) for this type too.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `smf.ols(....).fit()`, you fit your model to the data. I.e. for every data point in your data set, the model tries to explain it and computes a value for it. At this point, the model only tried to explain your historic data, without having predicted anything yet. Also note that `fittedvalues` is a property (or attribute) of model.

`model.predict()` is a method of the model to actually predict unseen values.